# Speed improvements for Perl's chameneos-redux in the Computer Language Benchmarks Game

Tags: perl, optimization

Ever looked at the [Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) (formerly known as the Great Language Shootout)?

Perl has some pretty healthy competition there at the moment.  It also occurs to me that there's probably some places that Perl's scores could be improved.  The biggest one is in the chameneos-redux script right now—the Perl version runs the worst out of any language: 1,626 times slower than the C baseline solution!

There are [some restrictions](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/flawed-benchmarks.php) on how the programs can be made and optimized, and there is Perl's interpreted runtime penalty, but 1,626 times? There's got to be something that can get the runtime of this program way down.

Taking a look at the [source code](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/program.php?test=chameneosredux&lang=perl&id=1) and [the challenge](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/performance.php?test=chameneosredux#about), how can the speed be improved?

Comment: It's an interesting challenge, but it doesn't belong here on stackoverflow IMO.

Comment: I'm curious as to your reasoning.  It seemed to fit pretty much in line with everything else about SO: question is specific, it's coding related, and there's a measurable way of telling if the question has been answered.  It deals with a topic that is difficult in programming: optimization, and specifically, optimization in Perl.  I have several places in my personal code that I've considered using threading techniques like shown in this benchmark, but after seeing the results here I am extremely hesitant.  If there's a better way of doing it, I want to know.  If not, then I know to avoid it.

Comment: Would it be a better question if it were "Why are Perl threads so $#@$&!*@# slow compared to other languages?"

Comment: I clarified the question a bit, specifically asking for ideas to reduce the runtime speed.

Comment: @Robert: You might want to post the original code here in case it gets changed in the future...

Comment: mobrule: They aren't slow! Creation of threads and communication is expensive. Parallel processing with threads is NOT. Unlike the threading in most other dynamic languages, the threads run on multiple cores.

Comment: I think this ia a weird place for a contest like that, nothing more. Not that I dislike a contest like that :-)

Comment: Huh?  No python one?  Then [What's this python implementation doing in the ranks?](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/program.php?test=chameneosredux&lang=python3&id=2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran the [source code](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/program.php?test=chameneosredux&lang=perl&id=1) through the [`Devel::SmallProf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::SmallProf) profiler. The profile output is a little too verbose to post here, but you can see the results yourself using `$ perl -d:SmallProf chameneos.pl 10000` (no need to run it for 6000000 meetings unless you really want to!) See [perlperf](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlperf.html#Devel%3a%3aSmallProf) for more details on some profiling tools in Perl.

It turns out that using [semaphores](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Semaphores%3a-Synchronizing-Data-Access) is the major bottleneck. The lion's share of total CPU time is spent on checking whether a semaphore is locked or not. Although I haven't had enough time to look at why the source code uses semaphores, it may be that you can work around having to use semaphores altogether. That's probably your best shot at improving the code's performance.

Comment: I could have told you without profiling, there really wasn't anything else that could that much time. The question is: what to do about it though.

Answer (score 2):

As Zaid posted, Thread::Semaphore is rather slow. One optimization could be to use the implicit locks on shared variables instead of them. It should be faster, though I suspect it won't be faster by much.

In general, Perl's threading implementation sucks for any kind of usage that requires a lot of interthread communication. It's very suitable for tasks with little communication (as unlike CPython's threads and CRuby's threads they are actually preemptive).

It may be possible to improve that situation, we need better primitives.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [version](http://gist.github.com/373847) based on another version from Jesse Millikian, which I think was never published.

I think it may run ~ 7x faster than the current entry, and uses standard modules all around. I'm not sure if it actually complies with all the rules though.

I've tried the `forks` module on it, but I think it slows it down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone tried s/threads/[forks](http://search.cpan.org/dist/forks)/ on the Perl entry?  Or [Coro](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Coro) / [Coro::MP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Coro-MP), though the latter would probably trigger the '*interesting alternative implementations*' clause.